# Are mob spawners versioned?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just made a mobspawner trap in my world after updating to 1.6.1, after the world (and chunk with the spawner) was created a while ago maybe in 1.2/1.3? In either case, the world was spawned before zombies dropped iron, potatoes and carrots.

Does this mean my mobspawner trap is never going to drop anything but rotten flesh? Or do I need to leave it longer?

Comment: The drop of mods doesn't depend on how the mobs are spawned at all.

Comment: Iron ingots, tools, potatoes and carrots are *rare* drops. You may not see them for a hundred zombies, be patient!

Comment: @OrcJMR I thought I had been. I collected 5-6 stacks of rotten flesh with no rare drops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items dropped from mobs killed from a Spawner have nothing to do with the Spawner itself. The Spawner only spawns the mob, it does not determine what the mob will drop when killed. A skeleton Spawner back from when spawners were first added into the game would still drop enchanted bows if the save was updated to the current version of Minecraft.